# could smtpclient block concurrent logins to an smtp server?

Tags: c#, .net

so i am developing an application where an email should be sent via smtp whenever an error occurs. Problem is: what will happen if 2 or more people use the same credentials to send the email? will the second request be blocked? I am using Smtpclient and Mail to accomplish the task - also i dispose everything once the email send and i am not using an asynchronous way to do it. 10x!

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be based on your SMTP server configuration. Most SMTP servers allow concurrent connections from the same user. SMTP transactions can be slow - I'd recommend using a database table or system event log for error logging. You can use a solution like [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) or [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) to handle email notifications, outside of the scope of your application(s).

Comment: thank, my main motivation is privacy...i know it's not that fast, but...i'd rather trust gmail and not some hosting account when i upload data via ftp or http and admins are sneaking around the files. Other than that i have used ftp before - it's very simple protocol and multiple logins at the same time were obviously not an issue. Both options have ssl of course, but it's not the lack of stealing the data during a request...but what happens to it once on the server. Of course i can simply zip the file and encode it to aes...but i don't know how to put aes this way on c#....yet.